# Cannot convert [SubclassOfErrorType] to expected type [ErrorType]

Tags: ios, swift, polymorphism, nserror

I have a custom `ErrorType` as shown below:

```
struct RGOServerValidationChallenge: ErrorType {
    var message: String
    var fieldIdentifier: String

    init(message: String, fieldId: String) {
        self.message = message
        self.fieldIdentifier = fieldId
    }
}
```

And an enum to represent the result I get from my API calls, be it a success or a failure:

```
enum RGOResult {
    case Success(AnyObject?)
    case Failures([ErrorType])
}
```

As you can see the `Failures` case takes an argument of an array of `ErrorType`.

However when I attempt to pass an array of `RGOServerValidationChallenge` into this enum, the compiler throws the following error:

`Cannot convert value of type '[RGOServerValidationChallenge]' to expected argument type '[ErrorType]'`.

I am not sure why this is happening as `RGOServerValidationChallenge` is a child object of `ErrorType` so polymorphism should allow me to pass the value without a cast.

**EDIT:**

I made a random protocol in the same file and made `RGOServerValidationChallenge` conform to it instead of `ErrorType`. I then edited the `RGOResult.Failures` to take this new protocol as an argument. The error still persists which suggests the problem is not with `ErrorType`.

**EDIT 2:**

Interestingly, passing a `[RGOServerValidationChallenge]` object straight in works, but when using a variable, it doesn't. What I mean is:

This works:

```
let errors = RGOResult.Failures([RGOServerValidationChallenge(message: "", fieldId: "")])
```

This does not:

```
let arr = [RGOServerValidationChallenge(message: "", fieldId: "")]
let errors = RGOResult.Failures(arr)
```

I am totally stumped...

**EDIT 3:**

I just ran this up in a Swift 3 playground as suggested by Vince and it appears to work. I guess this must just be a Swift bug that was patched in Swift 3. Looks like I'm just going to have to take the plunge and upgrade my code base.

Comment: Strange.  Works for me in Swift 3 when I cut and paste your code into a playground and declare ErrorType as a Protocol.  What version of Swift are you coding in?

Comment: I am using Swift version 2.3

Comment: This is odd, tried it in a 2.3 playground and it is fine.